# Unit Testing coverage socket.io with mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, redis, socket.io, mocha.js

Hi I am writing unit test cases for socket.io, test cases are passing but not reflecting in coverage how should I solve this issue. for more reference I posted code below
here is my code **Index.js**

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const redis = require('redis');

var client = redis.createClient(process.env.redisPort,process.env.redisHost);
var client1 = redis.createClient(process.env.redisPort,process.env.redisHost);
var client2 = redis.createClient(process.env.redisPort,process.env.redisHost);
var client3 = redis.createClient(process.env.redisPort,process.env.redisHost);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 35082;
server.listen(port);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('ws server');
});

io.sockets
  .on('connection', 
  (socket) => {
    console.log("Socket Connected");
    client.on('message',function(channel,msg){
      socket.emit('pickedup',msg);
    });
    client.subscribe('pickedup');

    client1.on('message',function(channel,msg){
      socket.emit('order-da-issue',msg);
    });
    client1.subscribe('da-issue');

    client2.on('message',function(channel,msg){
      socket.emit('crew-issue',msg);
    });
    client2.subscribe('crew-issue');

    client3.on('message',function(channel,msg){
      socket.emit('da-break',msg);
    });
    client3.subscribe('da-break');
  });
```

Here is my **index.test.js** Actually it's not doing any core testing it's testing only socket connection.

```
var io = require('socket.io-client'),
    assert = require('assert'),
    expect = require('expect.js');
describe('Suite of unit tests', function () {
    var socket;

    beforeEach(function (done) {
        socket = io.connect('http://localhost:35082', {
            'reconnection delay': 0,
            'reopen delay': 0,
            'force new connection': true
        });
        socket.on('connect', function () {
            console.log('worked...');
            done();
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            console.log('disconnected...');
        })
    });
    afterEach(function (done) {
        if (socket.connected) {
            console.log('disconnecting...');
            socket.disconnect();
        } else {
            console.log('no connection to break...');
        }
        done();
    });

    describe('First (hopefully useful) test', function () {
        it('Doing something else with indexOf()', function (done) {
            expect([1, 2, 3].indexOf(5)).to.be.equal(-1);
            expect([1, 2, 3].indexOf(0)).to.be.equal(-1);
            done();
        });

    });

});
```

Here is my **package.json**

```
"test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha ./test/*.test.js --exit",
"coverage": "NODE_ENV=test nyc --reporter=json-summary --all --reporter=text --reporter=html --report-dir=./coverage npm test",
"nyc": "nyc --reporter=json-summary --reporter=text --reporter=html --report-dir=./coverage npm run test"
```

Here is test coverage result

```
Suite of unit tests
    First (hopefully useful) test
worked...
      ✓ Doing something else with indexOf()
disconnecting...
disconnected...


  1 passing (144ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
 index.js |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 1-124             
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Thanks

Comment: Need to check dependencies first and to review `package.json`: I suggest fill it with settings over command arguments.

Comment: Also I did't saw `Index.js` import in test, looks like some kind of E2E test not the unit, that is why you did not get the coverage.

Comment: Hi@kirill.z will you please help me with an example.

Comment: is it still actual for u?

Comment: issue resolved @kirill.z